# Android: How to edit my ListView in another activity and return the edited result to the ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

So I have a listview in my activity1 class, what i want to do is:

Click on an item in the listview, which will open activity2 class, with 2 edit texts with the values from the clicked item in the listview, like name and age strings, I want to edit those values/strings in my activity2 class [by changing the edit texts], and send the edited values back to my listview in activity1 class, and show the edited values in my listview [for example show the name] instead of showing the old value/string that was in the listview before the edit.

I have tried many different ways, and I couldn't accomplish the goal, I would love if any of you could help me.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transfer your selected items data to your second activity like this code below

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ReportActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("MainDate", MainDate.getText().toString());
```

and in your second activity you have to get this data's and then manipulate them

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    MainDate = intent.getExtras().getString("MainDate");
```

then send back your manipulated data's to your first Activity just like before then update your list adapter

you can have data of your selected item in your first activity list by this code which lies on  yourList.setOnItemClickListener

```
Cursor Getdata = (Cursor)YourList.getItemAtPosition(position);
String Yourcolumnstring = Getdata.getString(Getdata.getColumnIndex("yourcolumnindex")) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for you're quick answer, I will try the tips you gave me, but I am not sure how: i.putExtra("MainDate", MainDate.getText().toString()); ... will get my "clicked view item" and send it to my activity2.

Comment: first you should get your selected item object and get your specific data that you want send to your second activity (as i've mentioned in the answer) then you can send your string via an intent to your second Activity.(Thank you for accepting)

Comment: I have a question... what is the MainDate? in you're example, because I need to get the listviews clicked row.. and send it.. for editing.. and I cant seem to make it work. unless I use "ArrayListName.get(position));"

Comment: MainDate is my textview which i needed to get data and send it to second Activity.you should use my latest code to get data from your list first in your list within setonitemclicklistener then when you get your specific column data you can send it via an intent to your Activity

Comment: @Arash how can we set back the updated data at same row in list view .??

Answer (score 0):

you should send your strings to activity2 and when retun from activity2 to activity1 should send your new strings from activity2 to activity1.you should your strings send as following:

```
String str = "My Data"; //Data you want to send
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name",str);
```

you should receive str in activity2 as following:

```
String name = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```